# How to convert base64 string to video in PHP?

Tags: php, video, base64, decoding, video-encoding

I have a base64 encoded string which my frontend team has provided me with.The string is a video which was encoded using base64. I want to convert that back into a video file using Php.

I am currently just using the following to decode the string but I don't know how to proceed further.

```
$decoded = base64_decode ($encoded_string);
```

There seems to be a way to convert images from string using ***imagecreatefromstring***() function, but I could not find a way to convert it into a video.

Thank you

Comment: you need to know the type of file that it should be - mp4,mov,flc,avi etc

Comment: okay let's say I do know, it's mp4.

Comment: at a quick guess perhaps something like `file_put_contents( "/path/to/movies/video.mp4", base64_decode( $encoded_string ) )`

Comment: thank you. it works. Please post it as answer if you want to

Comment: Side note: video is a storage intensive piece of data and encoding it as base64 makes it grow by 33 to 36%. You're wasting lots of bandwidth doing that.

Comment: ohh okay. Thank you. I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should know the video file type. you can decode to original format

```
$fp=file_put_contents('sample.mp4',base64_decode($encoded_string,true));
```

Comment: Beware that you're loading two copies of the complete original video into memory. This script is going to need lots of RAM.

Comment: can you share your solution recommendation? @Álvaro-gonzález

Comment: @HadidM Do everything you can in small chunks.

Comment: i have changed the code as per your suggestion. is it correct way ? @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: I've added an answer with some code since there's interest in the subject. The key point to understand about this one-liner is that `base64_decode()` returns the complete decoded string but doesn't remove `$encoded_string` so you have both in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Video streams tend to be very large so is isn't a good idea to convert them to plain text in the first place. We'd also need to know the exact mechanism (protocol, format...) used to deliver the base64 string. In any case, once there you can do something like this (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
$chunk_size = 8192; // Bytes (must be multiple of 4)
$input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$output = fopen('/tmp/foo.avi', 'wb');
while ($chunk = fread($input, $chunk_size)) {
    fwrite($output, base64_decode($chunk));
}
fclose($output);
fclose($input);
```

Smaller chunks reduce RAM usage and larger chunks improve I/O performance. You'll need to find a balance that works best for you.